# Does this environment have the same effect as I think?

Tags: environments, counters

I started using Latex in the class of a professor who gave a little template setup that used `amsart`. Since then, I took his command definitions and shortcuts into a class of its own. He counted questions like this,

```latex
% new environments 
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\newtheorem{bonus}{Bonus Question}
\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Question}
```

Now each time we use `\begin{question}...\end{question}`, the questions will get suffixed by an index, e. g., "Question n", here n being the appropriate number. This worked till I wanted a way of customising the n such as,

```
Question 1
Question 2
Question 4.7
Question 9
```

So I wrote another environment,

```latex
\newenvironment{prb}[1] % for custom numbering
    {\renewcommand\theinnercustomthm{#1}\innercustomthm}
    {\endinnercustomthm}
```

Now I'd use `prb` whenever I wanted to manually provide some arbitrary n.

However, revisiting my class file, I don't like the fact that I have two environments for almost the same thing. Therefore, I am trying to write a question environment that follows a counter unless an option argument is passed, in which case, it uses that instead of the counter value.

This is what I have,

```latex
\newcounter{QuestionCounter}
\stepcounter{QuestionCounter}
\newenvironment{question}[1][\arabic{QuestionCounter}]
  {
    \noindent\textbf{Question #1. }
    \ifnum #1=\value{QuestionCounter}% <--- don't forget this!
      \stepcounter{QuestionCounter}
    \else
    \fi
  }{}
```

Will this do what I want without breaking any of the previous documents written with the old definition of the question environment?

Comment: this isn't using a newtheorem definition foe question at al, so will change teh typesetting of any existing use of a question environment. The newtheorem definition doesn't just increment a counter it arranges suitable vertical space, prevents page breaks after the heading etc.

Comment: I have most of that changed with other packages anyways, I was mostly just concerned about the counter and spacing around the "Question n".

Comment: but the spacing is completely different in the new version (there is essentially no spacing applied at all)  compare `xxx \begin{Question} ...\end{Question} xxx` . With your new definition it will all be inline in the same sentence; and one with a `\newtheorem` definition the question will be set off as a displayed block with vertical spacing.   Given that the two layouts that you show are completely different how can we answer your question "Will this do what I want without breaking any of the previous documents" ? I would assume that it will break them.

Comment: I see, well, in that case could you propose a better solution?